# At what point can a difference between correlations be ignored?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, pearson-r

If for example, I have 2 correlation values (for the same two variables in two different time periods) 0.5925 and 0.6018, with a difference 0.0093, is this enough to defend a stance saying that the relationship for both periods is "the same", and that the difference is small enough to ignore? A large amount of correlation values I see are in the order of magnitude of 0.x, which leads me to think I am able to make this assumption.

Comment: Note that "the relationship" being the same encompasses more than "the correlation is the same" (even for a linear model we may have same correlation but different slope and intercept), and that since correlations are measured on a scale of -1 to 1 then naturally they will often look close together. You probably ought to clarify what you mean by "0.x"?

Answer (score 1):

You can test the difference between two observed correlations and see how large the probability is that the difference you observed is simply due to sampling variability, assuming that the "true" correlations are equal. This is a classical application of testing for [statistical-significance](/questions/tagged/statistical-significance). The result will depend on the number of observations that the two observed correlations come from and similar things.

[Diedenhofen & Musch (2015, *PLoS ONE*)](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0121945) give an overview of possible tests and describe the ['cocor' package for R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cocor/index.html) that implements them.

Comment: Are you sure that a hypothesis test will tell you the probability that the true correlations are equal?

Comment: @mark999: duh! Thank you! I have been correcting people's misunderstandings of NHST for years now, but I still mess up...

Answer (score 0):

in this  [link](http://www.real-statistics.com/correlation/two-sample-hypothesis-testing-correlation/) the author tells you to change your statistics (correlation values) population distribution into a normal one (by Fisher transform). Then, by Z-test, you can test your null hypothesis, e.g. if the 2 correlations are equal.